# TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'tuple'

Tags: python, jupyter

Will not execute. need to find the distance between lat and long.

```
divvy['Start Coordinates'] = (zip(divvy['from_station_latitude'], divvy['from_station_longitude']))
divvy['End Coordinates'] = (zip(divvy['to_station_latitude'], divvy['to_station_longitude']))

from geopy.distance import geodesic
dist = []
for i in range(len(divvy)):
    dist.append(vincenty(divvy.iloc[i]['Start Coordinates'], divvy.iloc[i]['End Coordinates']).miles)
    if (i%1000000==0):
        print(i)
```

Comment: Hi Brielle Kolf! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Also, read about how to create a [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

I presume "divvy" is a pandas DataFrame object. There are two comments about your code:

1. you probably misunderstand "zip" and "()", the correct usage is list(zip(stuff, stuff)) as this returns a list to be saved in "divvy". As it is, the current code saves copies of iterators in "divvy" instead of values.
2. it's probably faster to calculate distance for all entries in "divvy" instead of one-by-one

For example: 1 line method

```
dist = [vincenty((start_x, start_y), (end_x, end_y)).miles 
        for start_x, start_y, end_x, end_y in zip(divvy['from_station_latitude'],
                                                  divvy['from_station_longitude'],
                                                  divvy['to_station_latitude'],
                                                  divvy['to_station_longitude'])]
```

Your method:

```
divvy['Start Coordinates'] = list(zip(divvy['from_station_latitude'], divvy['from_station_longitude']))
divvy['End Coordinates'] = list(zip(divvy['to_station_latitude'], divvy['to_station_longitude']))


from geopy.distance import geodesic
dist = []
for i in range(len(divvy)):
    dist.append(vincenty(divvy.iloc[i]['Start Coordinates'],divvy.iloc[i]['End Coordinates']).miles)
    if (i%1000000==0):
        print(i)
```